# automate the reactivation of the service httpd after the instance reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have automated to stop the ec2 instance using lambda function also automated for starting also. I have initially activated the httpd service in that instance. I need to know whether it is possible to automate the process to reactivate the service httpd after the restart. i have another question also after every reboot the public ip of the instance changes why?

Thanks in advance.
Subramanian L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this command.
`chkconfig httpd on` This will restart the httpd service when the instance reboots.
You can refer this link as well: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/chkconfig-command-examples-for-red-hat-and-centos/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, can we automate the process. I mean the service httpd need to get started automatically without any command, as soon as the ec2 instance is restarted.

Comment: I tried using this command before stopping the instance after the reboot it automatically get started thank you so much.

Comment: I am happy it worked. Could you please upvote the answer if it worked, will help others too. Thanks